# Continuous rotation servo unresponsive to speed changes

Tags: otherservos, robot-calibration

I've been building a simple wheeled robot with the Parallax kit; it has two wheels powered by continuous rotation servos. Everything was running fine for the first six exercises until I removed the servos (because reasons) then put them back on. Now one of the servos runs at a fixed speed regardless of the PWM signal I send it. If I calibrate the servo with the pot so that the center value gives zero rotation, it remains still regardless of the signal. If I deliberately mis-calibrate the servo, it rotates at whatever speed it is set to for the center value (if you see what I mean). Regardless of what PWM signal I send, the speed does not change. The other wheel runs fine, and the code driving them is identical.

Did I break it? Is this something I could fix? Or should I just toss it and buy a replacement? I haven't seen or heard of behavior like this before, but I am definitely a relative novice with servos.

Edit: It stays with the "bad" servo if I swap connections. My best guess at this point is that the signal wire into the servo is bad.

Edit 2: I opened it up and tested the connections of the wires to the circuit board, and they are good. So it seems like it's the IC or circuit board, or something else I can't fix. Oh well.

Comment: do some basic troubleshooting ... swap the two servos ... see if the problem moves with the servo

Comment: You seem to have two accounts, [1](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/38123/jacob) and [2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/38125/jacobz). It is [not allowed to gain reputation from editing your own posts from another account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295007/4424636). You may merge your two accounts, see [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)